# How to remove MovieClip by selecting a row and pressing a delete button?

Tags: actionscript, movieclip

I have a datagrid, where rows are added. Whenever a row is added, a movie clip is added to the stage. I added a button to remove a row in the datagrid if the row and button are clicked, and all of that works perfectly well.

However, when I try to remove the movie clip relating to that row in the datagrid, it does not work.

My code is:

```
function removeloaditem(event:MouseEvent) {
datagrid.removeItemAt(datagrid.selectedIndex);
removeChild(MovieClip(datagrid.selectedIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
removeChild(MovieClip(datagrid.selectedIndex);
```

You need to understand what this line of code is trying to do.

```
datagrid.selectedIndex
```

This variable is just a Number. So, you are trying to cast a Number to a MovieClip.

```
MovieClip(1)
```

That does not work. You need a reference to the ***actual*** MovieClip object. Wherever you are creating your MovieClip object, you will need to store a reference to that object. You can have a plain Object store all of your references.

```
var objectList:Object = {};
```

and then, wherever you are creating the MovieClip, add this line:

```
objectList["reference_" + datagrid.selectedIndex] = "movieclip variable";
```

Replace "movieclip variable" with the reference to your movieclip object. After that, replace your current removeChild line with these two lines:

```
var movieclip = objectList["reference_" + datagrid.selectedIndex]
moveclip.parent.removeChild(movieclip);
```

Comment: Oh I see what you mean by the variable being just a number. But I do not understand the portion about replacing "movieclip variable" with the reference. Does that mean that both "reference_" and "movieclip variable" are the same term? And does the refer to a name of sorts for that movieclip?

Comment: You're creating a new movieclip to add to the stage, right? You must be. Like "var movieclip = new MovieClip();" "movieclip reference" is just placeholder text for where your movieclip instance variable name should go. So if you're doing "var someMovieClip = new MovieClip()" then you would replace "movieclip reference" with "someMovieClip"... get it?

Comment: Yeah I get it! It works fine when I try it on 1 movieclip. However, what if I were to have multiple movieclips of the same image? When I tried it, it removes all the movieclips, which makes sense considering they all have the same name. I have tried making the names different, by adding increasing numbers to the back of the movieclip instance name, but it does not seem to be working.